# Can two Linux installations share the same /home partition?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, kubuntu, opensuse

I am currently using OpenSuse 11.4 and Windows XP in laptop. I was planning to remove the Windows and switch to install Kubuntu. My current situation is that I have my root (/) and /home partition separated in OpenSuse.

Can I share the /home partition between OpenSuse and Kubuntu? How do I configure Kubuntu to use the existing /home partition during the installation?

BTW, the most recent Kubuntu is using ext3 file system whereas my OpenSuse is using ext3. Will this a matter for me to install Kubuntu? Any other issue I need to take care of?

Comment: during install when you get to the partitioning stage, select the partiton that has /home on it, edit the mount point for it to be mounted on to be /home, and UNSELECT "format this partition"

Comment: "the most recent Kubuntu is using ext3 file system whereas my OpenSuse is using ext3" Is this really what you meant to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible but in my case it caused many problems. Some time ago, as I tried to find the right distro for my visually impaired sister, we had dualboot of Pclinuxos Gnome and OpenSuse Gnome (same later with Ubuntu/OpenSuse). But there were some problems (like strange desktop behavior, resetting some settings etc.) with the hidden config files which were different for both distros. So I later created separate account for the second distro and only linked the user data to it. So it is not problem to have the same home partition, but I do not recommend to use the same home folder. :-)

Comment: Was posting a similar answer so it put it as a comment  on this on instead: It's possible to share the home partition. But I think that you might/will run into problems if you run applications that write configuration files to your home folder and if those applications are of different versions or uses different settings on the named distributions. You might be able to pull it off if you use separate user names on the two distros.