# Using the /home of a broken Linux installation as the /home of a fresh install on a different partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, installation

I have been using Manjaro in dual boot with Windows for a while but I completely messed up my Manjaro installation, likely when trying to install printer drivers. Manjaro does not boot anymore as the boot process does not go beyond the hp splashscreen. After 2 days of research I am giving up and will install Ubuntu on a different partition. My files in /home are fine (I could access them from a live USB).

Let's say that my broken installation is in `/dev/sda1`, can I remove every folder except for /home/, install Ubuntu in `/dev/sda2` and mount `/dev/sda1` as my home folder?

I found this related question: [Can two Linux installations share the same /home partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/303750/can-two-linux-installations-share-the-same-home-partition)
suggesting that I could, provided I deleted .config files. Is there anyhting else I should take into consideration?

Comment: Short answer is yes. Except move the contents of HOME to the root of your old drive.  Mount that partition to HOME of the new drive using fstab.  This will actually be an upgrade since you will have the entirety of sda1 as your home folder (assuming you partitioned it that way).  If I were you though.. I would back it up first so you don't hate me if a mistake is made.  You could also rsync it into the new drive.